# Adding a list of numbers to a query with CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to add a list of numbers to this query below:

```
DECLARE @MONTHS NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @YEAR NVARCHAR(10)

BEGIN
    SET @MONTHS = 'Q1'
    SET @YEAR = '2017'

    SELECT * 
    FROM netlication.dbo.iehResults
    WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,COLLDATE) = CAST(@YEAR AS INT)
      AND DATEPART(mm,collDate) IN (CASE @MONTHS WHEN 'Q1' THEN '1' End)
END
```

The query above works fine, but for the value Q1 I want to be able to pass a list of numbers 1,2 and 3

So I tried doing:

```
AND DATEPART(mm, collDate) IN (CASE @MONTHS WHEN 'Q1' THEN '1,2,3' End)
```

But I get a conversion error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2,3' to data type int.

Comment: Aside: Your `case` expression is return a string (`'1'`) rather than an `int` (`1`) while `DatePart` returns an `int`. The mismatch in datatypes is resolved according to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql). The best practice is to use the appropriate datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `DATEPART(mm,collDate)` you can use `DATEPART(q,collDate)` which will return the quarter and you won't need to compare with 3 values. But to compare, you must use `between` and 2 `case` statements.

```
DECLARE @MONTHS NVARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @YEAR NVARCHAR(10)
BEGIN
SET @MONTHS = 'Q1'
set @YEAR = '2017'
SELECT * FROM netlication.dbo.iehResults
WHERE DATEPART(yyyy,COLLDATE) = CAST(@YEAR AS INT)
AND DATEPART(q,collDate) = (CASE @MONTHS WHEN 'Q1' THEN 1 WHEN 'Q2' THEN 2 WHEN 'Q3' THEN 3 WHEN 'Q4' THEN 4 End)
END
```

However, performance wise it will be better to calculate the start and end dates of the quarter and then to filter by COLLDATE between them:

```
set @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@YAR, CASE @MONTHS
   WHEN 'Q1' THEN 1
   WHEN 'Q2' THEN 4
   WHEN 'Q3' THEN 7
   WHEN 'Q4' THEN 10 End, 1)
set @EndDate = DATEADD(q, 1, @StartDate)
SELECT * FROM netlication.dbo.iehResults
WHERE COLLDATE >= @StartDate and COLLDATE < @EndDate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AND DATEPART(mm,collDate) IN (SELECT 1 WHERE @MONTHS = 'Q1' 
                              UNION
                              SELECT 2 WHERE @MONTHS = 'Q1'
                              UNION
                              SELECT 3 WHERE @MONTHS = 'Q1')
```